# Error: Unable to create extension PLR in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plr

Well this issue has been a long problem for me. I am using PostgreSQL 9.5 (x64) on Windows 7 Enterprise (x64) and I have been running into problems when I try to run `create extension plr;`. I used [this](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/) link to donwload plr for windows. Copied all the files to respective directories. Added environment variables, but when I try to to run above command I get this error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "~/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/plr.dll": The specified module could not be found.
```

But, `.dll` file is present in the directory. I would be thankful if someone could help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you restarted postgresql service after adding environment variables? I don't know about windows 7, but it should be somewhere in control panel -> administrative tools (or something like that). Find service named "postgresqlXXX" and restart it.

Comment: Well, thank you for your help. But I ended up in another library mismatch error (since I am using PostgreSQL 9.6) and probably PLR is not available for Pg9.6 up till now.

Comment: Yes, you should downgrade to 9.5 for now